# Angular 11 - Including a language dictionary in a @component declaration - how to best declare?

Tags: angular, typescript, parameters, components, language-translation

In angular, modules have a declaration with options before exporting its class. These include selector, templateurl, styleURLs, moduleId, and I have seen others. But I haven't see an exhaustive list of all the options anywhere.

What I'd like to do is a simplified version of the following...

I put 15 language translations for words on a webpage in a separate .ts file as an @Injectable.

```
@Injectable()
export class Languages {
    public dialect = {
        "Vocab": [
            //english
            {
                "about": {
                    "tag1": "This is the text that will display as English for this object.",
                },
            },
            //Spanish
            {
                ...
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Then I have to import it in my app.module.ts, and set it up as a provider there as well.

```
import { Languages } from './languages';
  providers: [
    Languages,
    ...
  ],
```

Then I have to import it in my component's .ts, and then I have to add it to the constructor.

```
import { Languages } from "./app.languages";

@Component({
    selector: 'app.comp1',
    templateUrl: 'app.comp1.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.comp1.scss']
  })
  export class Comp1 {
    constructor( public languages : Languages) {}
```

Then I can call strings as variables in the HTML based on the language setting of the browser.

```
<a>
    <!-- Object description in English -->
    {{this.languages.dialect.Vocab[this.globals.languageIndex].about.tag1}}
</a>
```

Everything works really well, but I'd like to add a component-specific .ts per component and just use the @component declaration to pull it in to the local HTML, bypassing the app.module.ts altogether. I'd like to simplify - is there a good way to do that and still keep the core of the functionality in the HTML the same? I'm hoping for something like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app.comp1',
    templateUrl: 'app.comp1.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.comp1.scss'],
    providers: './app.comp1.language.ts'
  })
  export class Comp1 {
```

Is something like that possible?

Thanks.

Comment: "_But I haven't see an exhaustive list of all the options anywhere_" Where were you looking? https://angular.io/api/core/Component#component. And what's the purpose of this(sounds like an XY problem)? You don't need to declare anything as a service. Just create and export a variable and use it wherever you want --e.g: `export const langugage = [...]`

Comment: This helped! Your link showed me all the options, and "providers" was one of them. So, my "hoping for" above works as long as I also import the languages.ts file into the same .ts as the @Component declaration. To answer your other question, we want this to be modular so we can update the languages.ts files quickly from other automation. If you put this as the answer, I will check it. If not, I'll just answer the question tomorrow. Thanks and cheers!